# htaccess stopped working after moving website to subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, I moved the website.com to subdomain.website.com. The .htaccess file is located in the website.com/subdomain/ folder, it should work but it's not working.

Error message: The requested URL /title-123 was not found on this server.

Basically what it does is translates the website.com/product.php?id=123&title=hello to website.com/hello-123

The error is produced when trying to access subdomain.website.com/title-123

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

  # Turn mod_rewrite on
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/product\.php\?id=([0-9]+)&title=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %2-%1? [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+?)-([0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$2&title=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `\s`? urls don't generally start with whitespace...

Comment: What is DOCUMENT_ROOT for `subdomain.website.com`? Is there anything in root .htaccess also?

Comment: Comment out `RewriteBase /` line and try: `subdomain.website.com/subdomain/title-123` URL

Comment: Create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://subdomain.domain.com/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78474/discussion-between-anubhava-and-gazta).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and debugging of apache conf files and receiving expert's assistance i managed to fix it removing completely the .htaccess file and adding the rewrite rules in the apache VirtualHost directly.